# Syncing database with ArcMap and ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase

I am using SQL in Oracle to fill and empty feature class table, basically something like this:

```
INSERT INTO DAMO_W.BRUG (OBJECTID,CODE,NAAM,GLOBALID,SHAPE,CREATED_USER,CREATED_DATE,LAST_EDITED_DATE,LAST_EDITED_USER)  
SELECT  OBJECTID, CODE, NAAM, GLOBALID,SHAPE,CREATED_USER,CREATED_DATE,LAST_EDITED_DATE,LAST_EDITED_USER
FROM WS_BRUG;
```

The SQL runs and the table in the database gets filled, but in arcMAP when opening the feature it is totally empty, therefore there is out of sync between ArcSDE and Database.

I have restarted  ArcGIS connection and ArcMAP and no success, probably there is some trigger on ArcSDE or metadata that needs to be updated. Any tips on what could I do?

ArcGIS version: 10.6.1
Database: Oracle

Comment: Is the feature in ArcSDE versioned?

Comment: If you use versioning or archiving, you should not modify the table directly, but modify the "_evw" view instead (ie, DAMO_W.BRUG_EVW).  ArcGIS SDE geodatabases have a lot of complicated interactions between various tables and views, and if you try to manipulated them directly, you risk corrupting the database, or otherwise ending up with unexpected results.  The officially supported procedure for editing an SDE database with SQL is at:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/overview-edit-versioned-data-with-sql.htm

Comment: The version and archiving is off.

Comment: It is very possible that the objectid column ios the problem. tables regiserted with the geodatabase have a stored procedure or trigger (can't remember which) to generate OBJECTID values for each insert. If you are working with a geodatabase then you are better off using geodatabase tools to move data. Instead of SQL use the geoprocessing tools truncate and append, or delete and copy to move data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the data to appear in ArcMap it was necessary to commit on the database:

```
COMMIT WORK;
```